# Improve JQuery - Switches

Tags: jquery, css, toggleclass

I would like to improve my JQuery Script. I'm starting with it but I don't know if I'm doing "the correct way". Although the code is working the way I want, I think that I'm doing the wrong way with all those `toggleClass`

```js
  $(".switch-one .switch-body").click(function() {

  $(".switch-one .switch-body").toggleClass("not-selected");
  $(".switch-two .switch-body").toggleClass("selected");
  $(".switch-one .switch-conmutter" ).toggleClass("off");
     $(".switch-two .switch-conmutter").toggleClass("on");
     
       
  });

  $(".switch-two .switch-body").click(function() {
  $(".switch-two .switch-body").toggleClass("selected");
  $(".switch-one .switch-body").toggleClass("not-selected");
  $( ".switch-two .switch-conmutter" ).toggleClass("on");
     $(".switch-one .switch-conmutter").toggleClass("off");
          
  });
```

```css
label {
  left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.switch-one, .switch-two {
  height: 25px;
}

.switchers {
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
  
}

.switch-body {
  
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: #eee;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  float: right;
  z-index: 1;
}

.switch-conmutter {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #bbb, -1px -1px 3px #bbb;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
    
}

.switch-body:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  
  background: #F58E43;
  transition: background 0.5s linear;
  
}

.not-selected {
  
  background: #eee;
  transition: background 0.5s linear;
  
}

.on {
  left: 30px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.off {
  left: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switchers"> 
   <div class="switch-one"> 
   <label>SWITCH ONE</label>
   <div class="switch-body selected">
   <div id="switch-one-switch" class="switch-conmutter on"></div>
   </div>
   
     </div>

  <div class="switch-two"> 
   <label>SWITCH TWO</label>
   
   <div class="switch-body">
   <div id="switch-two-switch" class="switch-conmutter"></div>
   </div>
   
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I presume you are asking this question because you want to extend this to more than 2 switches?

Comment: No, just this two. I'm asking this because I think that all those toggleClass are "dirty code"... and should exist another way, better and cleaner than this to do it. Maybe I'm wrong and the code isn't that bad... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be simpler ways, but this is using jQuery and allows for as many other switches.

It is also assuming you will always want one switch active.

EDIT: Just saw you're looking to replace all the toggle/add/remove classes. This may not be a good answer.

```js
$(".switch-body").click(function() {
    $('.switch-body').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.switch-body .switch-conmutter').addClass('off');
    $('.switch-body .switch-conmutter').removeClass('on');
    $(this).find('.switch-conmutter').removeClass('off');
    $(this).find('.switch-conmutter').addClass('on');     
});
```

```css
label {
  left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.switch, .switch {
  height: 25px;
}
.switchers {
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
}
.switch-body {
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: #eee;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  float: right;
  z-index: 1;
}
.switch-conmutter {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #bbb, -1px -1px 3px #bbb;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.switch-body:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selected {
  background: #F58E43;
  transition: background 0.5s linear;
}
.not-selected {
  background: #eee;
  transition: background 0.5s linear;
}
.on {
  left: 30px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.off {
  left: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switchers"> 
    <div class="switch"> 
     <label>SWITCH ONE</label>
  <div class="switch-body selected">
   <div class="switch-conmutter on"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

    <div class="switch"> 
     <label>SWITCH TWO</label>
  <div class="switch-body selected">
   <div class="switch-conmutter"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

    <div class="switch"> 
     <label>SWITCH THREE</label>
  <div class="switch-body selected">
   <div class="switch-conmutter"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

    <div class="switch"> 
     <label>SWITCH FOUR etc...</label>
  <div class="switch-body selected">
   <div class="switch-conmutter"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use some other js framework (like [knockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/) in my case) for this purpose. See this snippet. Looks much simpler, isn't it?

```js
var SomeViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.flag = ko.observable(false);
  self.handler = function() {
    self.flag(!self.flag());
  };
};
ko.applyBindings(new SomeViewModel());
```

```css
label {
  left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.switch-one,
.switch-two {
  height: 25px;
}
.switchers {
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
}
.switch-body {
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: #eee;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  float: right;
  z-index: 1;
}
.switch-conmutter {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #bbb, -1px -1px 3px #bbb;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.switch-body:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selected {
  background: #F58E43;
  transition: background 0.5s linear;
}
.not-selected {
  background: #eee;
  transition: background 0.5s linear;
}
.on {
  left: 30px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.off {
  left: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switchers">
  <div class="switch-one" >
    <label>SWITCH ONE</label>
    <div class="switch-body selected" data-bind="css: {'not-selected' : flag, 'selected' : !flag() }, click: handler">
      <div id="switch-one-switch" class="switch-conmutter on" data-bind="css: {'off' : flag, 'on' : !flag() }"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="switch-two">
    <label>SWITCH TWO</label>

    <div class="switch-body" data-bind="css: {'not-selected' : !flag(), 'selected' : flag }, click: handler">
      <div id="switch-two-switch" class="switch-conmutter" data-bind="css: {'on' : flag, 'off' : !flag() }"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Much simple, of course, but by now I'm looking for doing it in JQuery. Thanks anyway!